# Converting data from LATIN1 to UTF8 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, character-encoding

I'm trying migrate a MSSQL database to MySQL. Using MySQL Workbench I moved the schema and data over but having problems converting the character encoding. During the migration I had the tool put text into BLOBS when there was problems with the encoding.

I believe I've confirmed that the data that is now in MySQL is *latin1_swedish_ci*. To simplify the problem I'm looking at ® symbols in one of the columns.

I wanted to convert the BLOBS to VARCHAR or TEXT with *UTF8* encoding. I'm running this SQL command on one of the columns:

`ALTER TABLE`bookdetails`MODIFY`BookName`VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Instead of converting the ® it is just removing them which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong? Not that reading half the internet trying to find a solution isn't fun but 3 days in and I think my eyes are about to give out.

Comment: you can right click the schema and click alter schema and change the collation

Answer (score 0):

MySQL workbench has a UI that is relatively simple to nav. If you need to change the collation of the tables or schemas, you can right click them on the Object Browser and go to alter table, or alter schema there you can change the data types, and set the collation to whatever you want.

Comment: I looked at the workbench for a while and I could change the collation but I could not figure out the character encoding. I found the actual generated script and could not change the encoding that was causing it to fail when migrating the data. The band-aid solution was to pull the encoded text into BLOB's and hopefully convert the encoding later.